# Meteor ^1.5.2 with React 16.x dead code elimination error in production

Tags: javascript, meteor

any idea how to implement the React 16.0.0 minify/uglify with Meteor ^1.5.2?

The browser console in production shows: **React is running in production mode, but dead code elimination has not been applied. Read how to correctly configure React for production: ...**

The link offered in the message is pointing to React documentation and solutions are offered for different environments however Meteor is specific in the sense that it builds its own bundle.

Thanks,
P

Comment: Meteor supports exact code splitting out of the box. It relies on you to specify your imports properly, but doesn't require anything else. The blog has some info on this https://blog.meteor.com/dynamic-imports-in-meteor-1-5-c6130419c3cd

Answer (score 0):

Meteor 1.6 has fixed this inconvenience.